# Why does a hypersurface in the FLRW solution not correspond to anything physical?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity

So I was watching some videos. Over [here](https://youtu.be/Pcd911qSTBk?t=2871) Padmanabhan claims that in a zero cosmological constant universe setting $a =1 $ in the FLRW metric is quite non-trivial:

> so there is a constant in the universe which you can determine
> only if this $a_0$ is given but the Friedmann equations do not fix
> $a_0$... Friedman equations with no extra physical input you will never
> be able to figure this out

[image]

Sorkin makes a similar point [here](https://youtu.be/9W_lxjnxulU?t=914):

> it has an arbitrary normalization; it no longer has a direct physical meaning. It's only the ratios of $a$, sort of $a$ at one time $τ_1$ to $a$ of $τ_2$ that have meaning.

I know while there were some solutions of General Relativity which are pathological from the initial value problem's formulation. I didn't think FLRW was one of them?

> The initial value problem then consists of specifying initial data for
> all fields on one such a spatial hypersurface, such that the
> subsequent evolution forward in time is fully determined.

Like naively I'd think that the initial value data corresponded to something physical? I feel something is amiss? Because if I take limits and go to a Newtonian mechanical regime I've never heard someone make similar claims for a fluid?

Comment: In my understanding of GR your are right. Among all solutions of Einstein field equations (there are infinitely many) that are straight the physical boundary conditions (initial values in terms of some physical quantities) that unequivocally defines the one physical solution.

Answer (score 5):

It's just a trivial question of rescaling coordinates, though Padmanabhan says it isn't.

He doesn't seem to define $a_0$, but I suppose it's the value of the scaling factor at the present time. His $a_\text{eq}$ is the value of the scaling factor when $ρ_\text{rad}=ρ_\text{m}$, and $aT_\text{CMBR}(a)$ is the CMBR temperature when $a=1$. These all change numerically if you rescale $a$, but not in an interesting way. It's essentially a change of units, though there are no conventional units for the scale factor. (If there were, they would be pseudounits like degrees.)

The usual convention is to take $a_0=1$. He wants to take $a_\text{eq}=1$ instead. On the same slide, below the part shown in your screen grab, he says "The epoch when $T_\text{CMB}=T_\text{eq}$ is unique; so $a_\text{eq}=1$ is the only epoch-invariant normalization". Obviously you could just as well take $a=1$ at some other unique time in the universe's history, such as the reionization time or the electroweak symmetry breaking time or the inflection point of $a(t)$. In any case, it doesn't matter; the normalization of $a$ is unimportant, and $a_0=1$ is usually more convenient.

He seems to think $a_0$ is important because of the alternate metric that you get when you substitute $r=ax$ (the last line of your screen grab of the slide). But that metric is independent of the choice of $a_0$, so I don't understand what point he's trying to make there.

Sorkin merely says that because of the arbitrary normalization, only ratios of the scale factor at different times have physical meaning, which is true.

Comment: (+1) Specifically, in Padmanabhan's notation, the coordinate rescaling that sends $a(t)\rightarrow \lambda a(t)$ (and hence $a_0 \rightarrow \lambda a_0$) for a constant $\lambda$ is just $x\rightarrow \lambda^{-1} x$. I cannot understand why he says that the transformation is not a coordinate rescaling.